# Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

My code :

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery-ui-modules/core',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies',
    'loader'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';
   
    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.sidebar', widget, {

            _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
                
                var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

                var btnplus = elem.data('btn-plus');
                var btnminus = elem.data('btn-minus');

                $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').trigger('processStart');
                this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                    'item_id': itemId,
                    'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val(),
                    'item_btn_plus': btnplus,
                    'item_btn_minus': btnminus,
                   
                }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
                $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').trigger('processStop');
               
                this._customerData();

            },

            /**
             * Update content after update qty
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} elem
             */
            _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
                var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

                if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                    $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                    if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                        window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                }
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            },

            _customerData : function ()  {
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);
            }
        }
        ); 
        return $.mage.sidebar; 
    }
});
```

Console Error 1 : https://snipboard.io/4NK3b5.jpg

Console Error 2 : https://snipboard.io/iqX8yF.jpg

Module : https://github.com/kirtinariya1/MinicartAjaxQtyIncrementDecrement

Comment: you need to add `'jquery',` in define!

Comment: Now i am getting https://snipboard.io/4lvOEy.jpg

Comment: you need to put condition like: `if (sections) { YOUR CODE }`

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery-ui-modules/core',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies',
    'loader'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';
   
    return function (originalWidget) {

        $.widget('mage.sidebar', widget, {

            _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
                
                var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

                var btnplus = elem.data('btn-plus');
                var btnminus = elem.data('btn-minus');

                $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').trigger('processStart');
                this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                    'item_id': itemId,
                    'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val(),
                    'item_btn_plus': btnplus,
                    'item_btn_minus': btnminus,
                   
                }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
                $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').trigger('processStop');
               
                this._customerData();

            },

            /**
             * Update content after update qty
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} elem
             */
            _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
                var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

                if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                    $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                    if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                        window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                }
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            },

            _customerData : function ()  {
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);
            }
        }
        ); 
        return $.mage.sidebar; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed your module and found that it is working fine, without any errors given in the console tab (you can see the video that I recorded)
https://www.loom.com/share/fa457f25e46f471ba493b6fd8a09846c